# Execute a method with JMX without JConsole

Tags: java, methods, jmx, invoke

How to execute a method with JMX without JConsole?

I want to invoke methods through JMX from Java code. With the code below I can get the *name of all methods* of the MBean interface but I am not yet able to actually **execute** them. Something is still missing, could anybody please help me?

```
private static String connectJmx() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    JMXServiceURL serviceUrl;
    JMXConnector jmxConnector = null;
    try {
        serviceUrl = new JMXServiceURL(URL);
        jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceUrl, null);
        MBeanServerConnection mbeanConn = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();

        ObjectName objectName = ObjectNameProvider.getObjectName();
        MBeanInfo info = mbeanConn.getMBeanInfo(objectName);

        MBeanOperationInfo[] operations = info.getOperations();         
        for (int i = 0; i < operations.length; i++) {
         sb.append(operations[i].getName()).append("\n");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LogManager.doLog(LOG, LOGLEVEL.INFO, "exception connection jmx",  e);

    } finally {
        try {
            if(jmxConnector != null){
                jmxConnector.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        //
        }
    }       
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The for cycle above collects the names of the methods. I want something similar, that instead of collecting the names, actually executes them.
Please do not recommend JConsole, it does not work for other reasons.

Comment: *"Please do not recommend JConsole, it does not work for other reasons."*  Please give the reasons.

Comment: we want to embed this functionality to our application, so when we distribute to the clients they can use without Jconsole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not put the code to invoke an mbean method. Here is a sample code to help you with that:

```
import javax.management.*;
import javax.management.remote.*;
import com.sun.messaging.AdminConnectionFactory;
import com.sun.messaging.jms.management.server.*;


public class  InvokeOp
  { 
    public static void  main (String[]  args)
      { 
        try
          { //  Create administration connection factory
                AdminConnectionFactory  acf = new AdminConnectionFactory();

            //  Get JMX connector, supplying user name and password
                JMXConnector  jmxc = acf.createConnection("AliBaba", "sesame");

            //  Get MBean server connection
                MBeanServerConnection  mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();

            //  Create object name
                ObjectName  serviceConfigName = MQObjectName.createServiceConfig("jms");

            //  Invoke operation
                mbsc.invoke(serviceConfigName, ServiceOperations.PAUSE, null, null);

            //  Close JMX connector
                jmxc.close();
          }

        catch (Exception  e)
          { System.out.println( "Exception occurred: " + e.toString() );
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Instead of this 'ServiceOperations.PAUSE' we need to specify the name of the method, and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the MBeanServerConnection JavaDoc, especialy the invoke method : 
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html#invoke(javax.management.ObjectName, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[], java.lang.String[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html#invoke%28javax.management.ObjectName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)